SLAM feature extraction does not generate map-database(*.msg)
I am working on building a model for outdoor map localization using OpenVSLAM and encounter this problem in feature extraction in this specific dataset and not able to generate map-database(*.msg)
feature extraction generated log file
I was able to generate the database files using a shorther video data but for this specific dataset I was not able to generate database file when finishing the feature extraction.
Since this is run on the container with shared resource at first I though it might be some problem with memory but I checked and there are still many TB left.
Any idea what this should be?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

contact the authors of the software you use.
